# hindi data xml in iphone

Tags: iphone

i am getting hindi xml data .how can in display in hindi language in iphone
please help me

```
\U00e0\U00b0\U00a8\U00e0\U00b0\U00b5\U00e0\U00b1\U008d\U00e0\U00b0\U00b5\U00e0\U00b0\U00bf\U00e0\U00b0\U201a\U00e0\U00b0\U0161\U00e0\U00b0\U00a1\U00e0\U00b0\U201a",
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show this in UILable you can assign text like this -

```
textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:@"\u0C35\u0c36\u0C37"];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting this type of response then not issue to encoding the iPhone can automatically convert into proper format. if it still not display then try out with UTF8StringEncoding method