# how to read hindi xml characters in iphone

Tags: iphone

hi i am getting xmlstring format like this format .this is hindi uicode.please help me how to convert this in hindi font in iphone application

समोसा

i was try this format;

```
NSString *str=@"&amp;#2357;&amp;#2361;&amp;#2340;&amp;#2379;&amp;#2325;&amp;#2375;&amp;#2357;&amp;#2354;";
NSData *data=str;       
NSString *content = [[NSString alloc]  initWithBytes:[response bytes]length:      [response length] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
lbl.text = content;
```

but i can't convert in hindi language in iphone

How I get these codes to display as Hindi script in my iphone app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [hindi data xml in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585582/hindi-data-xml-in-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

You can use &#**x**2357; We did this with XML-JAVA. Also try the answers here [hindi data xml in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585582/hindi-data)